# PHP update SQL nada Acontece

Tags: php

Boas, necessito de uma ajuda. Estou a volta deste problema quase a 1 dia. 
Neste Código que faz o update dos dados para o phpmyadmin não me altera nada mas tambem não me dá nenhum erro.

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("navegador", $conn);
//$id = $_GET['id'];

$ID = $_POST["ID"];

$Nome = $_POST["Nome"];

$NumeroBI = $_POST["NumeroBI"]; 

$Morada = $_POST["Morada"]; 

$Telefone = $_POST["Telefone"];

$DataNasc = $_POST["DataNasc"]; 

$Email = $_POST["Email"];

$Password = $_POST["Password"];

$is_admin = $_POST["is_admin"];

$sqlupdate ="update tb_utilizador SET Nome='$Nome', NumeroBI='$NumeroBI', Morada='$Morada', Telefone='$Telefone', DataNasc='$DataNasc',
            Email='$Email', Password='$Password', is_admin='$is_admin' WHERE ID='$ID' " or die (mysql_error());;
```

Comment: este comando foi descontinuado, utilize mysqli ou pdo

Comment: Onde que o phpmyadmin entra na dúvida?

Comment: Não entra directamente. é apenas a Base de dados que estou a utilizar . Mas já retirei

Comment: A base de dados é MySQL, se quiser por a tag correta. PHPMyAdmin é só uma ferramenta para edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitua seu código onde tem " $sqlupdate" por esse, talvez funcione .

```
$sqlupdate ="update tb_utilizador SET Nome='".$Nome."', NumeroBI='".$NumeroBI."', Morada='".$Morada."', Telefone='".$Telefone."', DataNasc='".$DataNasc."',Email='".$Email."', Password='".$Password."', is_admin='".$is_admin."' WHERE ID='".$ID."' ";
mysql_query($sqlupdate) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: não me dá erro nenhum mas também não actualiza os dados

Comment: coloca um echo $sqlupdate; antes de executar o mysql_query() assim você vai obter a query , tenta rodar no banco a query gerada se tiver rodando, o erro não é na query .

Comment: Se o ID for númerico não precisa das pelicas. WHERE ID='".$ID."'